# Trying to get a InputField result as a Int in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, format, input-field

[WhereTheInputFieldsAre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wXfg.png) So basically, an user is gonna type in the hours in a inputfield and im gonna get the amount they write as an int in my codes.
now my code looks like this:

```
public InputField hours, minutes;
public int wantedHours, wantedMinutes;
public int sysHour = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
public int sysMinutes = System.DateTime.Now.Minute;

void Update()
{
    if (sysHour == wantedHours && sysMinutes == wantedMinutes)
    {
        sendTheNotif = true;
    } else
    {
       sendTheNotif = false;
    }
}
```

basically what i want is that people are gonna write a value in an inputfield (for example: 12 as hours and 30 as minutes) and when the system hours match with the hours our user wants, a bool is gonna be true. the only thing left to do is get the inputfield inputs as wantedHours (which is an int) and wantedMinutes (which is also an int).

Comment: What does your `InputField` look like? Is `hours.text` a string? If so, then what value do you get when you debug it? You can check if your string is empty before sending it to be parsed like: `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hours.text){wantedHours = int.Parse(hours.text);}`

Comment: If you use `int.TryParse` the code won't throw an exception (but it still won't parse a string of the wrong format). Don't worry, `int.Parse` still works

Comment: well i dont understand the first question you asked Rahul, for the second one, i dont completely understand it but i dont think that hours is a string. i put an ".text" at the end of the code because it didnt worked otherwise. for the flydog, i cant use tryparse because unity gives me errors too. i just need to find a way to convert inputfield input to int.

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX Can you post your `InputField` class? Have you tried debugging to see if you get any value ?

Comment: sorry for not knowing anything but i dont know how to debug, and i dont know what do you mean by inputfield class. sorry for taking your time so much

Comment: if you are wondering, my inputfield and everything works like how they should. there is no problem with anything, i just need to get the things the player writes in inputfield as a int

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX What value do you get in your `hours.text` and `minutes.text` ? Basically the error is happening because of incorrect format of your above fields. The expected value is an integer. You can try this: `Convert.ToInt32(hours.text); Convert.ToInt32(minutes.text);`

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX Did you get this working?

Comment: umm so i guess i forgot to say that i kinda deleted the codes i put in the main question and i was just trying to get the things the player writes in inputfield as a int in a completely diffirent way. This is because i dont know if using ".text" is gonna work because the thing im trying to do is completely unrelated with texts. can you help me about this, without using the code i put in the main question?

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX Please update your code accordingly then with the relevant parts.

Comment: ok edited it just now

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX How are you population your `wantedHours` and `wantedMinutes` ?

Comment: i dont understand what are you talking about

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX In this line: `if (sysHour == wantedHours && sysMinutes == wantedMinutes)` , how are you getting the values of  `wantedHours` and `wantedMinutes` ?

Comment: thats the problem, i dont. im trying to find a way to get them

Comment: those thing are gonna be the things people write in the inputfields. what im asking for is  a way to get those things people write in the inputfields as wantedHours and wantedMinutes

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX Please show us your `View` code where you are binding the input to these fields. With the current code snippet, it is very difficult to determine how you are getting the values.

Comment: idk if the pic i added helps but yeah i did something

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX Not sure if you are using ASP.NET MVC here. What technology are you using to generate your UI?

Comment: oh my god i dont understand a single word from that. dude im using a computer and a program called unity, as you know. and the way i made the inputfield is by right clicking and selecting inputfield from the UI section. i didnt changed anything about the inputfield its a default input field. and all i want is to get the input from that inputfield as an int in my script. can you help me with just the last sentence?

Comment: @MMT-ElectriX I have added relevant tags for Unity. Somebody with experience in Unity might help you out.